# JMeter JSON Path Extractor error handling

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using the jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor and would like to put some error handling around it so that my log is not filling up with false negatives. I am unsure of the best way to do this and would like some insight.

Basically, I use it to parse a JSON response to check if something exists or not. If it exists, then the code does something based on the value. If it is blank, then it takes the default value and does a different action. This all works as expected - However, my log fills up with the following:

```
2017/05/30 15:50:57 WARN  - com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor: Extract failed com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Extracted array is empty
    at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.process(JSONPathExtractor.java:107)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:776)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to suppress just these warnings in the log (I don't want to hide all warnings, just this specific type) or to be able to put handling around it to not log them?

Comment: Could you format the output so it's easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a similar issue with that element.  I switched to the newer post processor called 'JSON Extractor' and now there are no errors.

Comment: Yeah in Jmeter 3.0 they have added new post processor called ('JSON EXTRACTOR')  . See [this link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) regarding its usage